# Excel Formula or VBA

Tags: excel, frequency

I am trying to write a formula that is only valid when it is within the frequency.

Here is the example:

We have 10 weeks.

If the frequency is 2 weeks(which the user can change, its a cell), then it will only happen every two weeks.

Let's say it starts on week 1. then week 2 will be 0 but week 3 will contain the value from the formula, etc.

How can I go about doing this? Is it possible to use a formula, or do I need to code this in vba.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the modulo-function [1]

```
MOD(number, divisor)
```

to flag specific weeks accordingly. That is, in combination with `if`, you can check if mod(weekNumber,interval) equals zero (or one in your case) and then display the required contents.

[1] http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/mod-function-HP010342698.aspx